# jQuery .data() and storing date information

Tags: javascript, jquery, datetime

I'm passing a JSON object back and forth using jQuery's .data().  One of the fields in the array is a string representing a date.  When I put the string into the .data() function, it's a string.  When I retrieve it, it's a js Date object (and it tacks on incorrect time zone information).  Is there a way to prevent this functionality?

Comment: Could you show a sample of your code? (And are you passing JSON (a string) or a JS object?)

Comment: Looks like it was due to another component on the page, not $.data().  Sorry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you're using the HTML5-style data attributes with jQuery .data(), which does coerce the values to the best match, see [jQuery online docs about .data()](http://api.jquery.com/data/#data-html5)

The work around is to use the .attr() method instead.

```
<div id="mydiv" data-two="2">

$('#mydiv').data('two') -> 2 // a number
$('#mydiv').attr('data-two') -> "2"  // a string
```

Comment: html5-style data is not changed to date type in javascript.

Comment: This appears to be the case, which is understandable that they don't want to go down the date-parsing road. It would be good to see some more specific code from the Questioner regarding this problem.

Comment: It's part of a bigger project, but I'll try to make a simple example from what I have.

Comment: Hmm.  This could due to another component on the page using the same object.  I tried some sample code, but it's working as expected.

Answer (score 1):

I had exactly the same thing.

I had the following code:

```
<div class="datasegment red" data-id="0045" data-name="0045" data-level="red" style="opacity: 1; height: 142.28571428571428px; ">
        <a class="datavalue" href="#" style="font-size: 24px; ">0045</a>
    </div>
```

and Javascript

```
var ID = jQuery(this).data("id");
```

When I had a "0045" in the field, it converted it directly to an integer that I did not want.

I then changed it to:

```
var ID = "";
ID = jQuery(this).attr("data-id");
```

It then correctly returned a string of "0045" as I needed it to.

This is a big problem in some cases, and I still have not found a descent work-around.

hth.
Shaun